# Chrome developer styles how to find elements.style?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

One of my divs is being set by JS and it shows in chrome dev tools like:

```
elements.style{
display: block;
}
```

I need to change this to display: none and can't find the code where the js is setting it. Is there any way I can somehow find where it's being set?

Comment: is it possible to show the relevant js?

Comment: No. It could be on any of 800 lines in multiple files. I was hoping that there might be some way I can break when it's being set or something. I'v tried using ctrl + f to search for display and stuff like that but no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an inline style is technically a DOM-tree modification you can just right-click the element in the 'Elements' tab, select 'Break on...' at the bottom, and then 'Attribute Modifications'.

I have just confirmed this to break just fine when I then change inline styles on that element in the console.

Comment: You saved me hours. Thanks